# Handle numerical values in a JSON created from MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am echoing a query from MYSQL in JSON format in PHP.
I then use the [importJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) script to import it to GoogleSheets.
I notice that since some numerical JSON fields are between double quotes, they are then imported to google sheets as string when I need these as number.

My PHP code to build JSON is the following:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pwd';
$dbname = 'db';

 $dblink = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
 //Check connection was successful
  if ($dblink->connect_errno) {
     printf("Failed to connect to database");
     exit();
  }

 $result = $dblink->query("SELECT ..");

  $dbdata = array();


  while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $dbdata[]=$row;
  }

 echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

I get this JSON:

```
[
   {
      "DateSummary": "08-2019",
      "USERID": "User1",
      "RM_B": "32636.23",
      "RB_B": "0.00",
      "PB_B": "1230.77",
      "RAW_LPS": "0.00",
      "RM_RB_B": "32636.23"
   },
   {
      "DateSummary": "08-2019",
      "USERID": "User2",
      "RM_B": "284583.43",
      "RB_B": "65522.50",
      "PB_B": "16399.07",
      "RAW_LPS": "0.00",
      "RM_RB_B": "350105.93"
   }
]
```

How can I manage from my PHP code not to get the numerical value between double quotes?

Comment: Perhaps `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`  to `json_encode()`.

Comment: There is no error message ...